# How do I sort a GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net

ASP.NET `GridView` sorting: I want to change the sorting direction from ascending to descending when I click the column name. But by default, sorting direction always showing ascending. Am I missing any property setting to toggle sorting direction? Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
protected void gridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{

    DataTable dataTable = myDataTable(strSQL);

    if (dataTable != null)
    {

        DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);

        dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + SortDirection(e.SortDirection);

        gridView.DataSource = dataView;

        gridView.DataBind();

     }

}
//e.SortDirection always showing ascending
```

aspx gridview column design for sorting:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="CREATE_DATE" HeaderText="Create Date" SortExpression="CREATE_DATE" />
```

Comment: I think it's the data you need to sort, not the grid itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try setting the [`AllowSorting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.allowsorting.aspx) attribute of the `GridView` to true in the markup?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True">
    <Columns>
        ...
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Or, you could do it in your code behind after the DataBind:

```
GridView1.AllowSorting = true;
```

This attribute allows the user to click on the column headers to sort on that column.

**Edit:** ***You actually have to create logic to decide whether to sort ascending or descending*** (`e.SortDirection` will only help you if your using a "data source control" like `SQLDataSource`).  Then you can just change your dataView.Sort code to some like this:

```
if(someCondition)
    dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " DESC";
else
    dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " ASC";
```

Where `someCondition` is your logic for deciding which way to sort (for instance you could keep track of what the last sort direction was for that column, then do the opposite if the user clicks it again).

Comment: yes. I had that property in gridview design. <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    EnableModelValidation="True" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
    GridLines="None" Width="720px" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small" 
    onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
        onrowcreated="GridView1_RowCreated" DataKeyNames="FILE_ID" AllowSorting=true 
        onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting">

Comment: @user994276 Have you tried explicitly setting the sort direction (just to see if it changes)?  Like this: `dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " DESC";`

Comment: Sounds great.  Since i am not using SQLDataSource e.SortDirection always defaulted Ascending. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Before you bind the data, sort it in the direction you want and then do:

```
gridview.DataSource=data;
gridview.DataBind();
```

If your datasource is `SQLDataSource` or something similar, just make sure your select statement does the sorting the way you want initially.

Comment: This is my code to sort Gridview column(i have included both files)

Comment: • protected void gridView_Sorting(object sender,